# Slow Motion of a video in Android with manually given intervals

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-video-player

I am new to android development. In my application, I need to do slow motion in video file. For example if i set a starting point(exactly at 60th second) and ending point(exactly at 120th second) in 3 minutes video file. Within this interval only,I need to show slow motion of my video file. Can anyone suggest that there is any default package or source code that will help for my requirement

Thanks

Comment: It's easy enough to control playback with `MediaCodec`.  You have "android-4.0" tagged, however, and `MediaCodec` isn't available until 4.1.

Comment: fadden,is any reference code available with MediaCodec for doing that operation.

Comment: Take a look at Grafika's "Play video (TextureView)" activity (https://github.com/google/grafika).  It will either pace playback according to the video's presentation time stamp values, or play it back at maximum speed.  You can alter SpeedControlCallback to show the frames at whatever rate you want.  Grafika is targeted at API 18, but this particular set of features would work on API 16.

Comment: @fadden I played video in slow motion by set `SpeedControlCallback`'s `setFixedPlaybackRate(10)` method. is there  any possible to set `PlaybackRate` for selected intervals